# Executar formulário ao clicar em um botão do navegador

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um formulário com um input file, e o que quero fazer é o seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu escolher um arquivo e apertar "ABRIR" preciso que meu formulário seja enviado ao clicar em "ABRIR".

> Meu form.

```
<form class="form5" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="Foto_us_sn_user" value="" style="display: none;">
    <input id="Bot_trocar_img_perf" type="submit" name="Trocar_foto_us_botao" value="Trocar">
</form>

<script>
    $('img.img_perfil_trocar').click(() => {
        $('[name="Foto_us_sn_user"]').click();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Dá um submit no formato quando o input do arquivo mudar

Comment: $('input').on('change', function(){$('form').submit()})

Comment: Funcionou, se quiser colocar como resposta pra mim marcar só colocar lá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com JQuery pode fazer como o Edson mencionou nos comentarios:

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
    $('form').submit()
})
```

E com JavaScript puro:

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('form').submit()
})
```